# Two css modal boxes to load two different

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set up a modal box on my website triggered via a link which is functioning as it should.

I wish to add a second Modal box to load up another piece of content too but both the buttons open the same box up and I cant seem to get to the bottom of it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">radio</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>radio fam</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1">events</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>events.....</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its more than likely a super easy fix but its been baffling me for a while now.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779157/opening-multiple-modal-boxes-on-one-page/51441854 similar to this question @Robbie Plenderleith

Comment: Variables are not scoped to script tags. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are using the two buttons to open the same modal, also overriding your variables in script.

It is easier and less code to just set your onclick of each button to do something like: `document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = 'block'` and `document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display = 'block'` for the second button since you already have ID's set on each modal.

This eliminates the excessive javascript code you have hard coded into your page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put 2 scripts tag> the reason your code dose not work is your the buttons, spans, divs have the same id and the same class.
that should works as you want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
#close1, #close2 {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#close1:hover,#close2:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn1">radio</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="close1">&times;</span>
    <p>radio fam</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2">events</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="close2">&times;</span>
    <p>events.....</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal1");
var modal2 = document.getElementById("myModal2")
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2")

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementById("close1");
var span2 = document.getElementById("close2");



// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "block";
}
btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
  modal1.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't use the same variables 'modal' and 'btn' multiple times as it overrides the previous one. So, make there 4 separate variables eg: modal, modal1, btn and btn1, and there you don't need to add multiple script tags.

Happy Coding Life :)